# How to make round Seitan sausages

Tags: seitan

I'm steaming my seitan (after I wrap it in foil), but it's hard to get it in perfectly round sausage shape. On the other hand, the seitan sausages I buy in stores are always perfectly round like a cylinder.. How do Seitan manufacturers get their seitan in this cylindrical perfect shape?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to make perfect sausage-shaped seitan would be to buy vegan sausage casing(assuming you are vegetarian or vegan since you are making your own seitan).

Something similar to [this](http://www.sausagemaker.com/23mm-15-16-Vegetarian-Casings-p/17-2250.htm).

Seitan in general isn't really smooth. And generally if it ever becomes smooth its probably over-mixed and becomes really tough. The casing provides a smooth surface and helps keep it in the round shape while you boil or steam it.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is foil-wrap them so there is some room to expand but a strong constraint once a certain expansion is reached. A couple of layers of tinfoil that are wrapped loosely, but twisted/clamped together firmly at the ends, will work well for baked seitan. Expect it to sometimes burst the foil, won't spoil it but don't make a setup where an accident can result from that happening.