# How can I make seitan sausages from a homemade seitan block?

Tags: vegan, sausages, vegetarian, seitan

So far I have made washed flour seitan blocks from wheat flour and seitan sausages from a seitan flour and chickpeas mixture.

I would like to use my homemade seitan block instead of the seitan flour for my sausages, as for me the wheat flour is easier to get than the seitan flour.

I have tried to roll the unsteamed seitan block into a sausage shape, but the seitan isn’t moldable enough to do that. (I have found [this related question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/71374/how-to-make-round-seitan-sausages), but I don’t think that the answers are applicable to using a seitan block as the basis for the sausages, as the homemade seitan block doesn't even get close to anything that resembles a sausage shape :) and I never had any problems rolling my sausages using the  mixture from seitan flour.)

When I tried to steam the seitan block as usual and grind it afterwards, the mixture wasn’t binding and the sausages were not holding their shape.

Is there a way to use homemade seitan blocks as a replacement for seitan flour to make seitan sausages? If yes, what would I need to do/change in order to do this?

Comment: What about molding the seitan into sausage shapes instead of blocks when you first make it?

Comment: Would you mind sharing your recipe/process? I've never had seitan (from washed flour or VWG) that wasn't malleable enough to be shaped into sausage-esque shapes, so curious what's going on for you.

Comment: sure, I don't have a proper recipe, but I usually use 1kg of wheat flour and approx. 650ml of water and knead until its a dough consistency. After 20-30mins of resting time I wash the dough in several rounds until the water rounds out clear. As a last step I fill it in a mason jar (optionally with soy sauce or other spices) and let the closed mason jar sit in a pot of boiling water for an hour. 
Before my last step, the dough is incredibly glutenous and I am not able to mold it much. I am also afraid that if I tried to use this as basis for sausages that they would be very dense and bland.

Comment: Dense and bland are a different set of issues; you'd take care of that by adding other ingredients in ... which presumably you'd have to do before steaming.